# Connect Power BI Cloud report to SAP HANA Cloud Database using cloud connector

Tags: powerbi, hana, sap-cloud-connector

I'm using Power BI Desktop to create some visualizations using SAP HANA Cloud Database. And for the development, I've installed and configured SAP cloud connector in my local machine and successfully connected with the HANA cloud database.

By using the server as localhost like below

[image]

The problem is, once I deploy my report to my Power BI cloud workspace it gives following error

[image]

Before publishing, I've changed the Server to the Cloud Connector's IP instead of localhost.